# Is there a way to store a binary file to HDF5?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I have a numpy `.npy` file and would like to store this in my HDF. I use the numpy format because the file has *dtype U22* and *H5py* does not like that.

Is there a way to store this binary file inside the HDF so I can access it using the dictionary format like `file['general/numpy_binary']`. I can try to provide an MWE if required.

MWE:

`a = np.array([['here',1,2,3], ['that',4,5,6]]).astype('S10')` which is a 2x4 array.

```
with h5py.File('dump.h5','w') as debug:
    g=debug.create_group('general')
    dset = debug.create_dataset('general/data', data=a.tolist())
```

results in this:

[resulting dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hpai.png)

I would like to see this data as a 2x4 table. Is that possible?

Comment: `h5py` handles variable-length strings just fine.  Could you, maybe, convert your `numpy` array to a Python list-of-lists (which `numpy` can do) and store that?

Comment: @TimRoberts i added an MWE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're showing seems to be a fault in your tool.  Observe:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([['here',1,2,3], ['that',4,5,6]]).astype('S10')
>>> a
array([[b'here', b'1', b'2', b'3'],
       [b'that', b'4', b'5', b'6']], dtype='|S10')
>>> a.tolist()
[[b'here', b'1', b'2', b'3'], [b'that', b'4', b'5', b'6']]
>>> import h5py
>>> h = h5py.File('data.h5','w')
>>> h.create_dataset('data',data=a.tolist())
<HDF5 dataset "data": shape (2, 4), type "|S4">
>>> h.close()
>>> h
<Closed HDF5 file>
>>> h = h5py.File('data.h5','r')
>>> h['data']
<HDF5 dataset "data": shape (2, 4), type "|S4">
>>> h['data'][0]
array([b'here', b'1', b'2', b'3'], dtype='|S4')
>>> h['data'][1]
array([b'that', b'4', b'5', b'6'], dtype='|S4')
>>>
```

Note that the shape is (2,4).  Both rows are present in the file.

Comment: you were right. If i switched to another hdf viewer, i can see the data.

Comment: tangent, but if i still wanted to add a binary file to an HDF file, how would i go about doing this? Is there a resource you can share. It doesn't necessarily have to be binary, how would i go about adding non-numerical data to an HDF file. Say, a pdf, an actual text file, a picture, etc.

Comment: Nope, that's not what HDF is for.  There is a spec you can read.  It stores datasets, and datasets are arrays or lists.

Comment: To store non-numerical data, you have to convert the data object to an array of data. Use opencv or PIL packages can be used to convert and save images. Text can be stored as arrays of strings (variable length strings are supported). I don't know how convert a PDF to array of data.